# C++ - What is the pointer array version of temp.pushback(temp[i])?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am wanting to know what the pointer array version for pushback is. I was using a vector and switched to a pointers pointing to an array. This is my first question on stackoverflow. I'm sorry if it's not very nice. I did look over the post requirements.

```
int * Ac::allMatches(string prefix) {
    int* temp;
    int pos1, pos2;

    BinarySearch(prefix, pos1, pos2);

    for (int i = pos1; i < pos2; i++) {
        temp.push_back(terms[i]); // Getting an error here in Xcode saying
                                  // "Member reference base type int* is not a 
                                  // structure or union"
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: There's no such function out of the box. If you don't want to use `std::vector` you need to roll your own. But I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I've considered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wanting to know what the pointer array version for pushback is

1. Compute the number of elements you would need in the array.
2. Allocate memory for the required number of elements.
3. Use array indexing syntax to access and modify the elements of the array.

```
int * Ac::allMatches(string prefix) {
    int pos1, pos2;
    BinarySearch(prefix, pos1, pos2);

    int size = pos1-pos2;
    int* temp = new int[size];

    for (int i = pos1; i < pos2; i++) {
       int index = i - pos1;
       temp[index] = terms[i];
    }

    return temp;
}
```

What this does not provide you but a `std::vector` does are the size of the array and automatic memory management.

It will be better for you to use `std::vector`. The overhead of using a `std::vector` is insignificant while you gain important funcionality.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but it didn't work. I'm working on it more now.